# got the folowing error :invalid reference format when running tests in docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, maven, testing, amazon-ecr

- I tied to run the following docker command, which should trigger TestNG XML suite (maven)
- image found in aws ecr.

```sh
docker run -t -v $(WORKSPACE)/reports:/target/surefire-reports/html 178595328311.east1.amazonaws.com:automation/$(MODULE_NAME)$(MY_BRANCH):latest -DxmlRunner=${TEST_COMPONENT}.xml
```

docker error message:

```
invalid reference format.
```

Comment: instead of $(sample) try ${sample}

Comment: Are any of the environment variables you reference set?  You'd get that error if both `MODULE_NAME` and `MY_BRANCH` are unset or empty.

Comment: I also tried without environment variables ( set the values hardcoded) and got the same error.